# how to perform query field not equal to 0 in elasticsearch

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch

i am working on elastic search
i want to do query on the doc that "alarmStatus" NOT EQUAL to  0
i did the following code

'''

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not":{
        "term": {
            "alarmStatus": 0
                }
            
      },
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "type": "meterdata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

'''

and it fail to perform not equal function, any help, thanks in advance

here is the query result i got ( i show only one as hit have 8k ..)

```
 "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 8067,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "meter",
                "_id": "7Hiii3QBSliyJ__J2921",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "header": {
                        "meterId": 12345,
                        "manufId": 2367,
                        "meterType": 7,
                        "swVersion": 4,
                        "dataCtrl": 123,
                        "accessNum": 179,
                        "alarmStatus": 0,
                        "dataConfig": 0
                    },                     
                }
            },
```

Comment: The query looks correct. Can you share your index mapping and a sample document that you want to match?

Comment: sorry what is index mapping? i am new to ES ,.... @Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GET mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html) i.e `GET /{{index-name}}/_mapping` to retrieve mapping definition for the index.

> [Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) is the process of defining how a document, and the fields
> it contains, are stored and indexed. Fields and mapping types do not
> need to be defined before being used. Using [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) (like
> in your case), new field names will be added automatically, just by
> indexing a document.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "header": {
    "meterId": 12345,
    "manufId": 2367,
    "meterType": 7,
    "swVersion": 4,
    "dataCtrl": 123,
    "accessNum": 179,
    "alarmStatus": 0,
    "dataConfig": 0
  }
}
 {
      "header": {
        "meterId": 12345,
        "manufId": 2367,
        "meterType": 7,
        "swVersion": 4,
        "dataCtrl": 123,
        "accessNum": 179,
        "alarmStatus": 1,
        "dataConfig": 0
      }
    }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "header.alarmStatus": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64763634",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "header": {
            "meterId": 12345,
            "manufId": 2367,
            "meterType": 7,
            "swVersion": 4,
            "dataCtrl": 123,
            "accessNum": 179,
            "alarmStatus": 1,
            "dataConfig": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What was he doing wrong?